# LinkedIn API to access who engaged with a post

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I am new to exploring LinkedIn and it's capabilities via APIs and I am finding it to be extremely confusing to get a solid answer. I was hoping someone can share their experience if this is possible.

Use case:
Look at a particular post engagement and see who liked it and what company they worked for.
These posts may belong to other accounts/companies, not my direct profile.

Is this allowed? If so, is there a particular combination of APIs I should explore?

Thank you

Exploration phase still.